# Replacing the value of a variable in RSRuby

Tags: ruby, r

There I am, happily using RSRuby to do some maths, when I encounter this odd behaviour:

```
irb(main):010:0> r = RSRuby.instance;
irb(main):011:0* r.assign 'e', 10
=> 10
irb(main):012:0> r.e
=> 10
irb(main):013:0> r.assign 'e', 20
=> 20
irb(main):014:0> r.e
=> 10
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by resetting the cache on the `r` object:

```
2.2.0 :026 > r.e
=> 11
2.2.0 :027 > r.assign 'e', 22
=> 22
2.2.0 :028 > r.e
=> 11
2.2.0 :029 > r.reset_cache
=> #<RObj:0x007fa269341508 @conversion=4, @wrap=0>
2.2.0 :030 > r.e
=> 22
```

My hunch is that the rsruby interface keeps a cache of the variables, assigning really does send the new value to R but rsruby has the old value cached on the ruby side, then resetting the cache will cause rsruby to fetch the value from R.

Comment: I had the same feeling indeed, glad to see I could have been right :)